# rio.write_crs() leaves empty crs

Tags: python, python-3, rioxarray, xarray

I have a dataset `ds` which looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 42, long: 1383, lat: 586)
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 1980-01-01 ... 2020-01-01
  * long         (long) float64 -1.732e+07 -1.73e+07 ... 1.73e+07 1.732e+07
  * lat          (lat) float64 7.332e+06 7.307e+06 ... -7.307e+06 -7.332e+06
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Data variables:
    tmean        (time, lat, long) float32 nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan
```

The spatial reference of the dataset are in epsg:3408, https://epsg.io/3408.

I am trying to assign the reference like this:

`ds.rio.write_crs('epsg:3408', inplace = True)`

but when I check it is not assigned and the spatial_ref is still `int32 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click over the paper here: Then you can see the crs.

[image]

[image]

it's something like this

Use this code:

```
data.rio.crs or data.rio.estimate_utm_crs()
```

Comment: There is no 'paper' in my editor.  How can I see it programmatically?  I tried `ds.crs` but it says `Dataset has no attribute 'crs'`

Comment: which IDE are you using? Install miniconda or anaconda that includes Jupyter Notebook in your browser.

Comment: I checked in Jupyter Notebook, those icons are not there. Is there not a way to return it programmatically?  I guess I can rephrase my question.

Comment: Use this: data.rio.estimate_utm_crs()

Comment: I think you meant `ds.rio.crs`

Answer (score 2):

See:
https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/crs_management.html

This should give you the correct CRS object:

```py
ds.rio.crs
```

Comment: This fails with `Dataset has no attribute 'crs'`

Comment: Did you use `.rio` before `.crs`?